# Get the list of merged branch from github in jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to get the list of merged branch in my master branch by using  `git branch -a --merged master` in jenkins. When i try locally i get all the branch name after doing `git pill/ git fetch --all`. the output shows locally:

```
git branch -a --merged master
    * master
      remotes/origin/master
      remotes/origin/devBranch/1.0.0
      remotes/origin/devBranch/1.1.0
      remotes/origin/devBranch/1.2.0
```

same thing when i do in jenkinsfile. it only shows the master branch.

**jenkinsfile**:

```
steps{
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'some_jenkins_cred_id', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD')]) {
                    sh("""
                    git config --global credential.username $GIT_USERNAME
                    git config --global credential.helper "!echo password=$GIT_PASSWORD; echo"
                    git fetch --all
                    git pull origin master
                    git branch -a --merged master
                    """)
                }
        }
```

i get output:

```
          + git fetch --all
          Fetching origin
          + git pull origin master
          From https://github.optum.com/paymentintegrity/orbit-spike-ness-logging
          * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
          + git branch -a --merged master
    ----> * master
            remotes/origin/master
```

Any way to get the list of branch in jenkinsfile?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--all` option to `git fetch` is useless here (there are cases where it does something useful, but you're not in one of those situations).  Don't use it.  It's not *wrong* but it doesn't help and will mislead you.  This is a general rule for all users of Git: unless you can describe what `--all` means—beyond this single sentence from [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> `--all`
>      Fetch all remotes.

—you should definitely *not* use the `--all` option.  (Ask yourself: *why did I use this option?*  If your answer is *because I wanted all branches*, note that `--all` never means "all branches".)

Now, the reason you're getting the results you get in Jenkins is because Jenkins has configured its own Git repository as a *single-branch* clone, and quite possibly also as a *shallow* clone.  These are all [options that you can set when you configure the Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/).  Setting up a single-branch clone makes the clone go faster (as does using a shallow clone of some specified depth).  But it means that you literally *can't* get the information you wanted to get.

You'll need to choose: do you want to be able to use `git branch -r --merged master`,<sup>1</sup> or do you want a faster clone?  If you want to be able to inspect the remote-tracking names with `git branch -r`, stop using a single-branch clone: put the *refspec* (search the linked plugin page for the word `refspec`) back to the standard default:

> The default refspec is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/REPOSITORYNAME/` where REPOSITORYNAME is the value you specify in the above repository "Name" field. The default refspec retrieves all branches. If a checkout only needs one branch, then a more restrictive refspec can reduce the data transfer from the remote repository to the agent workspace. For example, `+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` will retrieve only the master branch and nothing else.

---

<sup>1</sup>I used `-r` here because that's the option you really need, not `-a`.

Comment: i did try with -r and it only gave me 'origin/master'. Then i thought about cloning the whole repo in jenkinsfile step using 'git clone repo-url.git'. Now if i do 'git branch -r --merged master', i get all the merged branch. Don't know if it is right way of doing it and should i b cleaning up resources after getting the branches name i need.

Comment: `-r` means that `git branch` should list remote-tracking names (which are not exactly branch names, but are related). `-a` means: local branches plus `-r`. The fact that you don't *have* the remote-tracking names in the first place, because you've set Jenkins up to do a single-branch clone, is the problem.

Comment: Making a *second* clone is OK, but means that the *first* (single-branch) clone is now mostly wasted effort. It's not completely wasted, because you need that clone in order for Jenkins to see the file named `Jenkinsfile`. But suppose you fix your Jenkins setup to do a full (not single-branch) clone in the first place: then you won't need to make a second clone, which means the overall time to run the pipeline will drop.

Comment: this make sense. and you are right. i have with "discover branch" option as default and it pulls all the info when doing 'git branch -r --merged master'. I know you have have mentioned that  if i wanted a faster clone or do  'git branch -r --merged master'. how slow will it be if i don't  have fast clone? i didn't find any significant different in my test though. i was just working with a basic spring boot repo with minimum code.

Comment: The time it takes to clone a Git repository depends mainly on two things: the size of the repository, and the speed of transfer. When your repository is, e.g., the Linux kernel, a clone might take 5 or more minutes depending on the speed of the connection to the source repository (e.g., GitHub). A small repository, or even a big one that's very local (over a gigabit link), will take a few hundred milliseconds or maybe a second or two, so there's not that much point trying to optimize this.